# img.src prepends local path in FireFox?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am havng a very strange issue with FireFox and setting an img.src attribute dynamically. Here's the (really simple) code:

```
var img = new Image();
img.onload = function() {
    console.log("img is loaded! yay!");
};
img.src = varA;

console.log("img.src");
console.log(img.src);
console.log("varA");
console.log(varA);
```

My console output (in FireFox only) looks like this:

```
img.src
file:///Users/local/path/to/my/project/%22http://remote.com/path/to/my/file.jpg%22

varA
"http://remote.com/path/to/my/file.jpg"
```

If I hardcode the URL and set it to img.src it works fine, somehow using the variable causes it to prepend with a local path. Any ideas how to fix this? I am at a loss. Thanks in advance!

Comment: looks like the value of `varA` might literally be `"http://remote.com/path/to/my/file.jpg"` with the quotes - which is causing Firefox to think it is a relative path.

Comment: Are you running this on a webserver, or just on the local filesystem ?

Comment: Ahhh, yes! varA included the quotes and removing them fixed it (I was getting the value from a CSS attribute and did not replace the quotes). Pretty interesting that other browsers understood it - keeping us on our toes, I guess. Thank you - so glad it was a quick fix.

Comment: But on my machine it is working fine. And showing the correct output i.e, remote path(without the local path). **Firefox Version(33.1)**

Comment: @lemieuxster if you want to answer the question in addition to commenting, I'd be happy to accept it!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like the value of varA might literally be "http://remote.com/path/to/my/file.jpg" with the quotes - which is causing Firefox to think it is a relative path.